# How can I add a comma after each array item?

Tags: php

I need an array that looks like this (comma after each item except the last item)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 129.74,
    [1] => 130.74,
    [2] => 129.50,
    [3] => 129.10,
    [4] => 129.80,
    [5] => 129.74
)
```

And this is my code:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Actual FROM csvhoejde1");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

echo'<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo'</pre>';
```

Here my result from `$result`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 129.74
    [1] => 130.74
    [2] => 129.50
    [3] => 129.10
    [4] => 129.80
    [5] => 129.74
)
```

Comment: Loop the array and add a comma.

Comment: `print_r` is a function for debugging purposes. Iterate over your array and output data as you need.

Comment: how would you loop it?

Comment: Google, my friend.

Comment: With `foreach`, try to learn some basics of programming language that you use.

Comment: found alot of implode when i googled, but that just made it into a string

Comment: But the __real question__ is - __why__ do you need commas after values?

Comment: I would say, you shouldn't do it. What you are trying to do is changing data. I suppose it is only for presentational purposes. But then you only should change the presentation of the data, not the data itself.

Comment: $aray = array(10,27,4107,4314,3704,691);
var_export($aray);exit;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative method to looping would be to implode and explode the array.

Implode on comma and some other character, then explode on that other character.

```
$arr = explode("@", implode(",@", $arr));
```

https://3v4l.org/mXuPl

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the result and add `,` at last of every value except last one:

```
$arr = [];
foreach($result as $r){
    $arr[] = (end($result) != $r) ? $r . "," : $r;
}
```

Here `$arr` will contain the final array with comma appended to all values except last one.